# http 405 the method is unsupported by this URL

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, server

I'm making a little calculator in JEE, and i get a HTTP 405 method not supported.
I did override the post method, and still the same.

My code :

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Ma calculatrice</title>

 </head>
 <body>
  
  <h1>Bienvenue dans ma calculatrice !! </h1>

  <h3>Faîtes ici tous les calculs dont vous rêvez </h3>
  
  <form method = post action=Calculeuse>
  <input type=number name="nbre1" id="nbre1">
   <select name="select">
     <option value=" + " selected> + </option> 
     <option value=" - "> - </option>
     <option value=" X "> X </option>
     <option value=" / "> / </option>
   </select>
  <input type=number name="nbre2" id="nbre2">
  <button type=submit>Calculer</button>
   
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The bean that  i use :

```html
package com.calculator.bean;

public class Calculeuse {
 public double nbre1,nbre2, resultat;
 
  public String operat;
 
 public double getNbre1() {
  return nbre1;
 }

 public void setNbre1(double nbre1) {
  this.nbre1 = nbre1;
 }

 public double getNbre2() {
  return nbre2;
 }

 public void setNbre2(double nbre2) {
  this.nbre2 = nbre2;
 }

 public double getResultat() {
  return resultat;
 }

 public void setResultat(double resultat) {
  this.resultat = resultat;
 }

 public String getOperat() {
  return operat;
 }

 public void setOperat(String operat) {
  this.operat = operat;
 }

 public double calcul(double nbre1,double nbre2, String operat){
  
  
  if(operat.equals(" + "))
   resultat = nbre1 + nbre2;
  
  if(operat.equals(" X "))
   resultat = nbre1 * nbre2;
  
  if(operat.equals(" / "))
   resultat = nbre1 / nbre2;
  
  if(operat.equals(" - "))
   resultat = nbre1 - nbre2;
 
  return resultat;
  
 }
}
```

And the servlet :

I have to get the parameters of type number, i guess it's a mystake from the way i use the doPost but i can't find it.

```html
package com.calculator.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.calculator.bean.Calculeuse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Calcul
 */
@WebServlet("/Calcul")
public class Calcul extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Calcul() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 /**
  * @param nbre2 
  * @param operat 
  * @param nbre1 
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object nbre2, Object operat, Object nbre1) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Calculeuse calc= new Calculeuse();
  
  request.setAttribute("nbre2", nbre2);
  request.setAttribute("nbre1", nbre1);
  request.setAttribute("operat", operat);
  
     calc.setNbre1(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("nbre1")));
  calc.setNbre2(Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("nbre2")));
  calc.setOperat(request.getParameter("operat"));
  
  calc.calcul(calc.getNbre1(), calc.getNbre2(), calc.getOperat());

 
 
  System.out.println(calc.getResultat());
  
  
  request.setAttribute("calcul", calc);
  
     this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/CalculatriceVue.jsp").forward(request, response);
 
  
 }

 /**
  * @param nbre2 
  * @param nbre1 
  * @param operat 
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  this.doGet(request, response);
 }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Change the from method from POST to GET
otherwise you have to change the method which in servlet from doGet to doPost